# Asp.net Core MVC 2.1 -Authorization settings. -

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating an identification page for my project, I found an example in razor Pages on the internet that I managed to adapt it in MVC core and to execute it but at the level Startup it blocks!

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>  
{  
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;  
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;  
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;  
}).AddCookie(options =>  
{  
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login");  
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5.0);  
});  

services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>  
{  
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");  
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("Login");  
});
```

what should i do to adapt it to my mvc core.
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use correct pageName.If you add the Login Razor Pages directly under the `Pages` folder in MVC project, use `/Login`

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Login");
        });
```

Update:

In MVC, you could just set `[Authorize]` attribute on Index action, and use

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5.0);
        });
        services.AddMvc();
```

Comment: first of all, I want to thank you for your answer.
I do not want to use ragor page, my schema is the following - Models: Admin (user name, passeword) ...
- Controllers: Account -> (Login, Logout, ..), Home (-> (Index, ..)
- Views: Account-Login, Home-Index
So, my goal to lock the View Home in order to force the user to go through my View Account.